# nodejs - test failing but callback being called

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have a module which I export and which has a method `editHeroImage` which I am trying to test using `mocha`, `chai` and `sinon`. The modules has two objects that are passed as arguments, `connection` and `queries`. These are `mySql` objects, one containing the connection to the database and the other the query strings which are defined in their separate modules. The `expObj` which I am exporting and trying to test is a "helper" module.

I have successfully tested other methods of this module in the same way I am trying to test this method, but, however when I run into methods which use the `async` module for some reason, my tests no longer behave as expected. I wonder if I am missing something in this particular case, because I have tested other modules and methods which also use `async` and have not come across this behaviour.

When I run the tests, it logs "HELLO!" as expected but the assertion that the `callbackSpy` has been called, fails.

I am losing my mind here! Please help! What is going on? Could there be contamination between test suits?

Method under test:

```
expObj.editHeroImage = function(connection, queries, postId, postData, callback) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(next) {
      var qString = queries.getSinglePostById();
      connection.query(qString, [postId], function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        if (!results.length) {
          console.log('NO POST FOUND WITH ID ' + postId);
          return callback();
        }
        next(null, results[0].hero_image);
      });
    },
    function(heroImageId, next) {
      if (!heroImageId) {
        console.log('HERO IMAGE IS NEW - NEXT TICK!');
        return next();
      }
      // Delete resized images of hero image
      var queryStr = queries.deleteResizedImages();
      var resizedVals = [heroImageId];
      connection.query(queryStr, resizedVals, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }
        console.log('DELETED RESIZED IMAGES OF HERO IMAGE ' + heroImageId);
        var qString = queries.updateHeroImagePath();
        var values = [postData.hero_image, heroImageId];
        return connection.query(qString, values, function(err, results) {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }
          console.log('UPDATED HERO IMAGE ' + heroImageId + ' WITH PATH ' + postData.hero_image);
          next('break');
        });
      });
    },
    function addHeroImage(next) {
      var qString = queries.insertImage();
      var values = [postData.hero_image, postId];
      connection.query(qString, values, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        next(null, results.insertId);
      });
    },
    function addHeroImagePathToPost(heroImageId, next) {
      var qString = queries.saveHeroImageId();
      var values = [heroImageId, postId];
      connection.query(qString, values, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        next();
      });
    }
  ], function(err) {
    if (err && err !== 'break') {
      return callback(err);
    }
    console.log('HELLO!');
    callback(null);
  });
};
```

Test, with set-up:

```
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
var sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(sinonChai);
var expect = chai.expect;

describe('HELPERS', function() {
  var testedModule,
    callbackSpy,
    fakeConnectionObj,
    fakeQueriesObj,
    fakePost,
    fakeSnakeCaseObj,
    queryStub,
    connectionStub,
    manageStub,
    fakeCamelCaseObj;

  beforeEach(function() {
    fakePost = {};
    fakeConnectionObj = {};
    fakeQueriesObj = {
      getPostIdFromImage: function() {},
      insertResizedImages: function() {},
      createPost: function() {},
      getPostImages: function() {},
      getPostsAlternativesImages: function() {},
      getSinglePostById: function() {},
      getAllImages: function() {},
      insertImage: function() {},
      deleteMainImage: function() {},
      deleteResizedImages: function() {},
      updateHeroImagePath: function() {},
      saveHeroImageId: function() {}
    };

    afterEach(function() {
      queryStub.resetBehavior();
    });
    fakeSnakeCaseObj = {
      sub_title: '123',
      hero_image: '456'
    };
    fakeCamelCaseObj = {
      subTitle: '123',
      heroImage: '456'
    };
    callbackSpy = sinon.spy();
    queryStub = sinon.stub();
    manageStub = sinon.stub();
    connectionStub = {query: queryStub};
    testedModule = proxyquire('./../../../../lib/modules/mySql/workers/helpers', {
      './../../../factories/notification-service': {
        select: function() {
          return {manageSns: manageStub};
        }
      }
    });
  });

it('edits hero image', function() {
    var _post = {
      id: '123',
      title: 'vf',
      sub_title: 'vf',
      slug: 'vf',
      reading_time: 4,
      created_at: '123',
      published_at: '123',
      deleted_on: false,
      hero_image: 'hero_image_path'
    };
    var _postId = '123';
    queryStub.onCall(0).callsArgWith(2, null, [{hero_image: '55'}]);
    queryStub.onCall(1).callsArgWith(2, null);
    queryStub.onCall(2).callsArgWith(2, null);
    testedModule.editHeroImage(connectionStub, fakeQueriesObj, _postId, _post, function() {
      console.log(arguments); // --> {'0': null} as expected
      callbackSpy.apply(null, arguments);
    });
    expect(callbackSpy).has.been.calledWith(null);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion is probably executing before your async function has returned.

There are a number of ways to ensure your async functions have finished executing. The cleanest is to format your mocha test differently.

```
describe('...', function () {
    var callbackSpy;

    before(function () {
        var _post = {
            id: '123',
            title: 'vf',
            sub_title: 'vf',
            slug: 'vf',
            reading_time: 4,
            created_at: '123',
            published_at: '123',
            deleted_on: false,
            hero_image: 'hero_image_path'
        };
        var _postId = '123';
        queryStub.onCall(0).callsArgWith(2, null, [{
            hero_image: '55'
        }]);
        queryStub.onCall(1).callsArgWith(2, null);
        queryStub.onCall(2).callsArgWith(2, null);

        return testedModule.editHeroImage(connectionStub, fakeQueriesObj, _postId, _post, function () {
            console.log(arguments); // --> {'0': null} as expected
            callbackSpy.apply(null, arguments);
        });
    });

    it('edits hero image', function () {
        expect(callbackSpy).has.been.calledWith(null);
    });
});
```

Notice that I have wrapped your assertion in a describe block so we can use `before`. Your actual logic for setting up stubs and executing the class has been moved to the `before` block and a return added, this ensures the async function is complete before moving on to your assertions.

Your other tests may have passed, but they will also be susceptible to this and it is purely a timing issue.

Comment: Indeed you were right about it being a timing issue. However using your suggestion of wrapping the assertion in a describe block and using the before function to set-up the test resulted in my stubs no longer working correctly. However taking your suggestion about timing into account I managed to solve the issue by using the `done` callback within my test suit.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed @Varedis was right about it being a timing issue. However using your suggestion of wrapping the assertion in a describe bloack and using the before function to set-up the test resulted in my stubs no longer working correctly. However taking your suggestion about timing into account I managed to solve the issue by using the done callback within my test suit. By keeping the set-up I made a slight change and my tests suddenly passed:

```
it('edits hero image', function(done) {
    var _post = {
      id: '123',
      title: 'vf',
      sub_title: 'vf',
      slug: 'vf',
      reading_time: 4,
      created_at: '123',
      published_at: '123',
      deleted_on: false,
      hero_image: 'hero_image_path'
    };
    var _postId = '123';
    queryStub.onCall(0).callsArgWith(2, null, [{hero_image: '55'}]);
    queryStub.onCall(1).callsArgWith(2, null);
    queryStub.onCall(2).callsArgWith(2, null);
    testedModule.editHeroImage(connectionStub, fakeQueriesObj, _postId, _post, function() {
      callbackSpy.apply(null, arguments);
      expect(callbackSpy).has.been.calledWith(null);
      expect(callbackSpy).has.not.been.calledWith('FDgdjghg');
      done();
    });
  });
```